# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, массивы

Я не знаю, пошёл спать.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите 10 чисел!");

        double[] ch = new double[10]; //???????????????????????????????

        System.out.println(ch.length); //я тупой?

        for (int x = 0; x <= ch.length; x++) {
            ch[x] = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(ch[x]); // я тупой?
        }
        double res = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= ch.length; i++) { // а это я вообще не проверял
            res += ch[i];
        }

        double res1 = res / ch.length; //тут всё работает. точно.(не точно(точно))

        System.out.printf("Среднее арефмитическое этих чисел равно : %.1f\n", res1); //это ведь так вычисляется?

    } //конец
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос просто офигенно сформулирован. Все бы так спрашивали

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 10;
    double sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Введите " + n +  " чисел!");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += in.nextDouble();
    }

    double res = sum/n;

    System.out.printf("Среднее арефмитическое этих чисел равно : %.1f\n", res); //это ведь так вычисляется?
```

Comment: Та решение можно найти за 2 секунды.
Почему моё то не работает? Что не так в том что я написал? >:(

Comment: for (int x = 0; x <= ch.length; x++) {
        ch[x] = in.nextDouble();
}
Тут пердит с этой ошибкой.
Говорит мол много ввожу, нету столько в массиве.

Comment: @Гений, так нормально сформулируй вопрос. Длина массива на единицу больше индекса последнего элемента. В условии измени `x <= ch..` на `<`

Comment: Я пробовал, не работает.

Comment: В обоих циклах замени!

Comment: Олексий, не работает.

Answer (score 3):

Индексы в массивах на Java начинаются с нуля, а не с единицы и поэтому заканчиваются на длину массива минус один. Классический цикл `for`, который тут используется, генерирует значения индексов от нуля до длины массива включительно. И вот это включительно и есть ошибка. Для того, чтобы было невключительно условие продолжение цикла `for` должно быть `i < array.length`, а не `i <= array.length`. То есть, как только `i == array.length` цикл, совершающий итерацию по массиву `array`, должен завершаться.

Comment: Ну я не настолько тупой.
Попробуй в компилятор всунуть, не работает это

Comment: Ну видимо ты все-таки не так "всовываешь". Замени в коде все `<=` на `<`